# How to update standart Django model (auth_user)

Tags: python, django

I would like to add new field into existing model (in this case - User(auth_user)). For example, there are fields "first_name", "last_name", "email".. etc. Please advise how best to implement this?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Answer (score 1):

You can extend or create you own substitute User model. In my point of view is better to create your own.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
```

and then in your settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'
```

I hope this help you.